# How to insert elements from arrayList to a map, sorting by their name?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a Worker class with grade and name for each worker.
I need to write a method that will return me a sorted map by the workers name..
The sort is by a Comparator I build that calld workersComparator..
And there is a limit that I cant write the word Worker(The class) more then once..I need to work generic way..

The comparator is like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class workersComparator implements Comparator<Worker<?>>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Worker<?> worker1, Worker<?> worker2) {
        return worker1.getName().compareTo(worker2.getName());
    }
}
```

and the method is like this:

```
public static Map<Integer,?> createMap(){

    TreeSet<Worker<?>> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(new workersComparator());
    for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++) {
        treeSet.add(workers.get(i));
    }
    Map<Integer,?> workersMap = new TreeMap<>();
    int index = 1;
    int pointer = 0;
    while( pointer < treeSet.size() ){
        workersMap.put(index,treeSet.iterator().next());
        index++;
        pointer++;  
    }
    return workersMap;  
}
```

Comment: What it the purpose of this? Your `TreeMap<Integer ...>` is simply an array.

Comment: I have a problem when I try the "workersMap.put...".

Comment: Is it right what I did?

Comment: No. Just use an "enhanced for" iteration over the treemap.

Comment: Can you help me? what is the correct way to move all my workers arrayList to a map sorted by their names?(By using the Calss Worker only once in the method and without the word String..inly generic)

Comment: What output do you expect to get? What output are you actually getting? Please update your question with those details.

Comment: I am expecting to get a sorted Map(TreeMap or HashMap) by the objects(Worker) names..and i can need to be generic so i cant use the word String and i can use "Worker" only once

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a `java.util.List` to a `java.util.TreeSet` and have it sorted by name, you can use the constructor of `java.util.TreeSet`. But the Worker class needs to implement the Comparable interface.

In this case you could simply use:

```
TreeSet<Worker> worker = new TreeSet<>(workers);
```

Here is a full code example you can try out:

```
public class ArrayListToSortedMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Worker> workers = Arrays.asList(new Worker("john"), new Worker("jane"),
            new Worker("james"), new Worker("maria"), new Worker("andre"));
        TreeSet<Worker> worker = new TreeSet<>(workers);
        worker.stream().map(Worker::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static class Worker implements Comparable<Worker> {

        private String name;

        public Worker(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Worker o) {
            return name.compareTo(o.name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of this code:

```
andre
james
jane
john
maria
```

Alternatively you can use a comparator in a stream and convert the ArrayList to a map, but the code is more convoluted:

```
public class ArrayListToSortedMap2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Worker> workers = Arrays.asList(new Worker("john"), new Worker("jane"),
                new Worker("james"), new Worker("maria"), new Worker("andre"));
        Map<String, Worker> worker = workers.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Worker::getName, Function.identity()));
        worker.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static class Worker {

        private String name;

        Worker(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("worker -> %s", name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
andre=worker -> andre
james=worker -> james
john=worker -> john
maria=worker -> maria
jane=worker -> jane
```

Comment: OP is using a `Comparator` - and I would not recommend this approach as it creates a class that is not "consistent with `equals`". This may cause strange and unusual behavior.

Comment: I tried it but i need to return a map from the function..and thats a treeSet and the compiler wont let me

Comment: @OmerOhana: please check the updated answer which converts an List to a Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap which sort values by key. You will not require any comparator. Please see following snippet.

```
 Map<String, Worker> sortedWorkers = new TreeMap<String,Worker>();
    for(Worker worker:workers){
         sortedWorkers.put(worker.getName(),worker);
    }
```

This will add worker into map in sorted order by workers name.

By sortedWorkers.values() will return all workers sorted by their name.

Comment: Its not possible for me because I have a cant use the Word String and i can use "Worker" only once in the method..

Comment: Didnt get it. Can you pls elaborate more?

Comment: I have an arrayList of "Workers<?>". Worker<?> is a generic class and one of the fields is a String name.
Now i need to create a method that takes the array and insert all the workers in a Map..the key will be a running key(1....n) and the value will be the worker him self.
the problem is i cant use the word "Worker" more then once, and cant use the word "String" in the method..
the method should return the map.